# How to combine default input with conditional in order to perform calculations in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to make a function that calculates something depending on the input. I have tried to make it so that if the input is not given, then it be set as `0` by default. I will either provide `a` and `d` or `b` and `c` but no crossover.

```
import numpy as np

data_t = np.random.uniform(2.25, 2.75, size=10)
data_a = np.random.uniform(9.5, 10.5, size=(20,10));  data_a = list(data_a)
data_b = np.random.uniform(6.5, 7.5, size=(20,10));   data_b = list(data_b)
data_c = np.random.uniform(14.5, 15.5, size=(20,10)); data_c = list(data_c)
data_d = np.random.uniform(18.5, 19.5, size=(20,10)); data_d = list(data_d)

def TEST(t, a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0):
    t = np.array(t)
    if a and d == 0:
        m, n = np.array(a.shape)
        x1 = np.array([[b[jx, ix] + t[jx]  for ix, i in enumerate(range(n))] for jx, _ in enumerate(range(m))])
        y1 = np.array([[c[jx, ix] + t[jx]  for ix, i in enumerate(range(n))] for jx, _ in enumerate(range(m))])
    elif b and c == 0:
        m, n = np.array(a.shape)
        x2 = np.array([[a[jx, ix] - t[jx]  for ix, i in enumerate(range(n))] for jx, _ in enumerate(range(m))])
        y2 = np.array([[d[jx, ix] - t[jx]  for ix, i in enumerate(range(n))] for jx, _ in enumerate(range(m))])
    else: 
        raise ValueError('Something is wrong.')

test = TEST(t=data_t, a=data_a, b=0, c=0, d=data_d)
```

I am obviously doing something wrong related to how `Python` interprets `if` combined with `and` but I have no idea how is the correct way to do it. I end up getting the `ValueError` I created.

- How is the correct way to do what I am trying to do to?

Comment: your if statment says if `a` is true AND `d == 0`, instead i think you mean `if a == 0 and d == 0`

Comment: Thank you, @Chris Doyle -- I cannot believe I did not see that. I answered the question with your suggestion below.

Comment: Why are you converting your numpy arrays to lists? And why are you using semicolons?

Comment: Also, aren't you "losing" elements when zipping `data_t` with one of the other arrays? If you zip, say, `data_t` and `data_a`, you get 10 tuples which means half of the rows of `data_a` were dropped. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Chris Doyle, for setting me straight. As he said in his comment above, I should set the conditional to be `if a == 0 and d == 0`. I also improved the rest by:

```
def TEST(t, a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0):
    if a == 0 and d == 0:
        x1 = np.array([[i + j for i in k] for j, k in zip(t, b)])
        y1 = np.array([[i + j for i in k] for j, k in zip(t, c)])
        return x1, y1
    elif b == 0 and c == 0:
        x2 = np.array([[i - j for i in k] for j, k in zip(t, a)])
        y2 = np.array([[i - j for i in k] for j, k in zip(t, d)])
        return x2, y2
    else:
        raise ValueError('Something is wrong.')
```

Everything works fine now and it is all thanks to @Chris Doyle. Thank you again.